# error validation not displaying as expected when the file is attached using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

currently working on jquery validator for the custom file input field. Where user click **yes** radio button some more field can be displayed then if the user click the attach button when the user upload more than 2 mb file, if the user trying to attach some other format it should say you have upload more than 2mb file the alert and not supported format was coming perfectly fine but I need an  error message should come in the top of the form. **You have missed 1 fields. Please fill before submitted** this was not working.

here is the current jquery code

```
        $preview.hide();
    $(".checkfile").on("change", function(e){     
            var filename = this.value;
            var files = this.files;
            var URL = window.URL||window.webkitURL;
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').attr("href", url).show();
            $(this).next('.check').prop("disabled", true);
            var myfile = $(this).val();    
            var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
            if (ext == "pdf" || ext == "jpeg" || ext=="jpg") {
                $(this).next('.check').val(filename);
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').hide()
                alert('Invalid File Type')
                $(this).next('.check').val('');
                $(".checkfile").val('');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if(e.currentTarget.files[0].size>=1024*1024*2)
            { 
                alert('File Size cannot be more than 2 MB');
                $('.ctm_widt').val('');
                $('.custom-file-input').addClass("errRed");

                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').hide()
            }else{
                $('.custom-file-input').removeClass("errRed");
            }
        });
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/b07eL63k/1/)

Thanks in advance

Kindly please help me for this question

Comment: @any suggestion for the above question

Comment: what's erroring out?

Comment: @Daemedeor what is that mean i am not getting that

Comment: i'm not particuarly understanding this phrase:  should come in the top of the form class. You have missed one field.

Comment: hi currently with  my code if the user click the next button the error mesage will display in top of the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92808/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-daemedeor).

Comment: @Daemedeor can you please join the chat if possible