# jquery validation not working on hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Working on jQuery validator initially some of the field where display none so  when the user click next button the error message was showing **You have missed 1 fields.  Please fill before submitted** this was working perfect as i expected. Because I gave `ignore:".chk_Field",`. But when the user click yes radio button user can able to see some more fields. without filling any of the field If user click the next button still it should say **You have missed 5 fields.  Please fill before submitted**  but currently it was saying  **You have missed 1 fields.  Please fill before submitted** this is not happening with this line of code `ignore:".chk_Field",`

Here is my jquery code

```
function apply_validation() {
    $(".educationForm").validate({
        ignore:".chk_Field",
        onkeyup: false,
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

            var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();

            if (errors) {
                var message = 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill before submitted.';
                $errorMessageDiv.html(message);
                $errorMessageDiv.show();
            } else {
                $errorMessageDiv.hide();
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },
        errorPlacement: function () {
            return false;
        },
        highlight: function (element) {

            if ($(element).is(':radio')) {

            } else {
                $(element).addClass('errRed');
                $(".chk_field_hlt").addClass('errRed_chkb');
                $('#imageUploadForm').addClass('errRed');
            }
            $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {

            if ($(element).is(':radio')) {} else {
                $(element).removeClass('errRed');
                $(".chk_field_hlt").removeClass('errRed_chkb');
            }
            $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');

        }
    });
}
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/120s9xxj/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466643/jquery-validate-enable-validation-for-hidden-fields

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi i tried using ignore:[], but no use :(

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi if i add ignore[]  it was not considering the hidden valeus

Comment: I have one query do I need put any condition where the user click yes radio button where i am seeing the div block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this line of code:

```
$("#expy").find(".chk_Field").removeClass("chk_Field");
```

Here:

```
 $(".wrk_clp").click(function () {
        if ($('input[name=rad_emp]:checked').val() == "yes") {
            $expDiv.show();

            $("#expy").find(".chk_Field").removeClass("chk_Field");
}
```

I just tested and it seems to work.

Comment: yes buddy i suppose to put answer for the same this will work for sure :)

Comment: can you please look for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223588/error-validation-not-displaying-as-expected-when-the-file-is-attached-using-jque