# Custom error class not applying to all the checkbox when the button is click using jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

Currently I am facing issue in checkbox where initially when the user click the **yes** radio button a panel with some filed will be displayed when the user click the next button the error class was applying only for the first check box but it should apply for all the check box the question might be very easy but some how I am not getting the exact result. Here is the jquery code

```
        $(".phy_clp").click(function() {
    var inputValidation = $('input[name=phy_clp]:checked').val();

    if (inputValidation === "yes") {
        $phyexpyDiv.show();
        $(".phyexpy").find(".chk_field_hlt").removeClass("chk_Field");

        //$(".chk_field_hlt").addClass('errRed_chkb');
    } else if (inputValidation === "no") {
        $(".chk_field_hlt").removeClass('errRed');
        $(".phyexpy").find(".chk_field_hlt").addClass("chk_Field");
        $phyexpyDiv.hide();
    }

});
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/t8jz98sf/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: kindly please do let me know why i got negative for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `highlight` and `unhighlight`, refer to [the source code of the plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js) where you can see the default code that handles `radio` buttons properly.

Since you're over-riding this default code, you'll need to do something similar for your `checkbox` elements.

```
highlight: function (element) {
    if (element.type === "checkbox") {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass('errRed').removeClass('text-error-black');
    } else {
        $(element).addClass('errRed');
        $('#imageUploadForm').addClass('errRed');
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');
    }
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    if (element.type === "checkbox") {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('errRed');
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass('errRed');
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');
   }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/t8jz98sf/1/**

Comment: thanks for the answer can you please kindly look the question if you have time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33223588/error-validation-not-displaying-as-expected-when-the-file-is-attached-using-jque

Comment: @Mahadevan, I just took the time to answer **this** question for you.  At least have the courtesy to review and discuss before asking me to look at yet another version of this problem.  Your last five questions are so similar to each other, nobody can decipher what you really want. Please focus on editing & fixing your question rather than posting a bunch of duplicates. Also, might not be a bad idea to concentrate on improving your grammar and sentence structure so we can understand you better.